# I can't apply same css style to two "row-fluid"

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML and CSS code.

**HTML**

```
<section id="content">
    <article id="areaRegister">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <?php include 'formulario.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="contentBarcode">
                    <div class="codigoBarras">
                        <header><h4>Código de barras generado!</h4></header>
                        <canvas id="registerBarcode" width="230" height="100"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article id="areaSearch">
        <div id="toEdit" class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <?php include 'formulario.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="contentBarcode">
                    <div class="codigoBarras">
                        <header><h4>Código de barras generado!</h4></header>
                        <canvas id="editBarcode" width="115" height="70"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-fluid .span6:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

For example, with the css above: The first span6 the first "row-fluid" has left padding of 10%, but the first span6 the second "row-fluid" does not have it, what happens? If it is the same style.

Also does not work if I want the second span6 each "row-fluid" has margin-left: 0; alone puts the first "row-fluid" but the second does not.

Other issue is when I try to apply any style to the first span6 of #toEdit:

```
#toEdit div:first-child{
    padding-left: 10%;
 }
```

It's supposed to apply to the first span6 but observing the code in the development tool of chrome and firefox, I realize that the top style applies to  :/

**FIXED**

The problem was: With JS prepend a H3 to second "row-fluid" and bootstrap doesn't allow put any element between "row-fluid" div and "spanN" div

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/6FKdh/

Comment: Yes, works but areaSearch is in "display: none" so that the two articles are tabs in a menu then, when I press on AreaSearch shows everything in this article and arearegister is hidden .. that influences the css?

Comment: Please either delete your question, or post your solution and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure.. in 3 hours I will accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

The problem was: With JS prepend a H3 to second "row-fluid" and bootstrap doesn't allow put any element between "row-fluid" div and "spanN" div

Thanks anyway to @Miljan Puzović